# UDP Broadcast - PHY/Port Delay

Tags: udp, broadcast

I have a small isolated LAN which consists of one server and five clients. The server and clients are connected to the same switch and there are no other switches in the network. From the server I'd like to broadcast a UDP packet for synching all of the clients. I simply need the clients to receive the UDP packet at the same time. This broadcast will happen every 0.5 seconds, perhaps even be reduced to every 1 second.

My question is this: how do I ensure my switch will simultaneously send the message at the same time to all clients? I assume all switches send the message to one client at a time very quickly to appear being sent at the same time, but this will not be good enough for my application.

I am OK with a switch adding delays between receiving the UDP packet from the server and broadcasting to the clients, but I do need the switch to broadcast to all clients simultaneously.

Are there specific switches, or switch features, I may need? My only other option is redo my application with PTP, including PTP enabled switches. But I'd rather not go down this path if I can.

For more clarity:
The clients will be embedded devices which I can control the processing of the received UDP, this processing will be deterministic and have the same timing on all clients since all clients are identical hardware and firmware. Cable length will be identical at about 3 meters, this means the transmission of signal will be below 1 microsecond.

When I say "simultaneously" I am referring to the switch broadcasting on all ports or PHYs at the same time and not sending the broadcast signal to client 1, then client 2, ..., then client 5.

Comment: Please define "simultaneously" if the number is very small, the choice of switch is probably irrelevant, because there will be other source of noise such as other processes running on the client machines.

Theoretically, If you go small enough you would have to measure the length of the network cables, since speed of light would become a factor (realistically this won't be an issue, because networking gear doesn't have that level of precision).

Comment: @DavidT - I've updated my post. Let me know if this helps. For some reason my previous comment is missing.

Comment: I am asking you to define what your tolerance is between the packets arriving at each of the devices. Zero time is not an option, even the best hardware in the world will have variances / tolerances. It is likely there are other factors, for example a Gigabit network by definition will take at best 1 nanosecond to deliver one bit of data.

Comment: The broadcast needs to be received within <200 ns across all five clients. The switch can add delays for when it starts processing the send, but once it starts sending to client 1 that same message must be sent to all clients within 200 ns, regardless of other traffic.

Comment: I am not going to be be able to give an answer for that tolerance. However to help someone else - how big is your message ? Per my previous point that time window only allows for 200 bits at Gbit speeds.

Comment: The UDP payload will be 8 bytes.